# insert query in jsp

Tags: javascript, sql, jsp

I got invalid number error and missing comma number.
I think this statement has some problem

```
String sql="insert into proptemp (auto_number, proptemp_id, reg_date, odtemp_max, odtemp_min,    

idtemp_max, idtemp_min, weather)

values('"+auto_number+"','"+proptemp_id_chk+"',to_date('"+reg_date+"','yyyy-mm-dd'),

'"+odtemp_max+"','"+odtemp_min+"','"+idtemp_max+"','"+idtemp_min+"','"+weather+"')";
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you to write sql query in JavaScript.

To get an instance of the INSERT query builder:

```
var q = squel.insert();
```

At least the table name and one field must be supplied:

```
alert(
    squel.insert()
        .into("students")
        .set("name", "Thomas")
);

/*  INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES ("Thomas") */
```

Squel out how to treat each field value based on its runtime type, same as it does for UPDATE queries:

```
alert(
    squel.insert()
        .into("students")
        .set("name", "Thomas")
        .set("age", 29)
        .set("score", 90.2)
        .set("graduate", true)
        .set("nickname", null)
);
/*  INSERT INTO students (name, age, score, graduate, nickname) VALUES ("Thomas", 29, 90.2, TRUE, NULL) */
```

And same as for UPDATE queries, you can use the usingValuePlaceholders option to stop Squel from automatically placing string field values within quotes:

```
alert(
    squel.insert({ usingValuePlaceholders: true })
        .into("students")
        .set("name", "?")
        .set("age", 29)
        .set("score", 90.2)
        .set("graduate", true)
        .set("nickname", null)
);
/*  INSERT INTO students (name, age, score, graduate, nickname) VALUES (?, 29, 90.2, TRUE, NULL) */
```

[click for more functions](http://hiddentao.github.com/squel/#insert)